# Theoretical about handling large data from web in c#

Tags: c#, bigdata

I am new to handling large data files
I want to extract from an internet source that have 13 columns and about 1.5 million lines
During the extract process, I am pulling the data about 5000 lines minute (API limitations)
I am coding in c# and will really appreciate some assistants
In which type of data storage souled I save the data.
An array? , stack? Nodes?
If anyone can Offer me a solution that will be great

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It depends on data complexity, and how do you want to post-process rh data. 1.5 million lines of 1 character is very different to a long unicode JSON string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what will you do with that data afterwards (that includes wether you actually need all that data in memory at the same time also).

If possible, and you have a normalized key in your data (or can build a good hash from it), I'd use a `HashSet` for it, since it's efficient both in memory and performance and if the hashes are good it'd approach O(1) performance when looking up.

Remember the maximum object size you can store by default in .NET applications is 2gb (I think you can override this limitation on .NET 4.5 if targeting 64 bits), so if you need more than that, you'd require different objects and manipulate in batches.

1.5 million lines doesn't say a lot: those "lines" could be 10 bytes in size, or several megabytes each,

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need to store the data at all.

Take a look at Reactive Extensions

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg577609.aspx

If you can use the [Observerable.Aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(%22System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.Aggregate%60%601%22);k(Aggregate);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) Method

to process your aggregate on the fly and so don't need to rescan over all records after the read process.

ELSE

You can use `List<YourDataRecordType>` if the memory consumation is less than 1GB (by my exp.)

If you need unknown complex queries later on and/or a persistent data store, just use SQLite

Answer (score 0):

You can easily embed for example a RavenDB, and push each row as an object. Performance should not be a problem and you end up with safe and queryable data source (for example if you needed to find out quickly what data you already got, in case you have to re-start data download).

[Here is how to embed a RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.0/csharp/server/deployment/embedded)

I think that the big issue is that you really don't want to loose the data you already downloaded, because you are limited with the API.